# How to unzip a BZIP2 file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, bzip2

I have a Bzip2 file I want to decompress in Flutter
But I did not find a way
Of course, this is a package
https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/archive/versions/2.0.11
But there is no example for Bzip2
Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The archive package does not document how one can decode bzip2 archive. But fortunately its quite simple.

As of [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2), Bzip2 can only compress single files. If you know which file is encoded it is easy to extract the file.

For me, I had a compressed file that was called `test.dem.bz2` and i expected a file called `test.dem`

**Unzipping**

```
import 'package:archive/archive_io.dart';
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';

final bytes = File('test.dem.bz2').readAsBytesSync();
final List<int> archive = BZip2Decoder().decodeBytes(bytes);
```

The result of the `decodeBytes` operation is a List of unsigned 8 bit values. These represent the extracted files.

**Creating the file extracted file**

if the function in which you are executing the code is async use

```
await var file = File('test.dem')..create();
await file.writeAsBytes(archive);
```

otherwise use

```
var file = File('test.dem')..createSync();
file.writeAsBytesSync(archive);
```